# My Folders Become Hidden System Files And Access Denied?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, virus

I have an external hard disk , just connected to another system and when i connected to my own computer one of my folders which contain photos become hidden system files AND all folders in it rename to same name !?!? and my access is denied ( Screenshot )

[image]

I **tried to change ownership** but i can't

Any solution !?

Comment: @HackToHell So what , is there any way to get it back

Comment: Scan the drive and open it in Linux and locate your files.

Comment: @HackToHell sorry is there any way so i can run linux in windows , virtually i am not and expert , any linux already virtualized so i can run it in machine

Comment: @HackToHell which version should i download Fedora , CentOS , Ubuntu , ...

Comment: @echolab . Its not important which distributions you use. but ubuntu is good

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Comment: Before you go installing new a new OS, or freaking out about viruses -- To me it seems like the file system on the drive may be corrupted, which can easily happen to drives being plugged and unplugged at the wrong time.  Have you done a basic disk check on the drive? Have you checked it in another computer?

Comment: Did you modify this folder while attached to the 'other' computer?

Comment: @techie007 i don't think so cause this happen to all my JPG files other files are in good health , i didn't modify anything , i just plug it to another computer after watching a movie , safe remove it

Comment: @HackToHell I just intalled Fedora 16 (Verne) , could you give me some advice

Comment: @echolab Now you will be able to access all the folders on it easily, also here's some info for recovering files http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13706/recover-deleted-files-on-an-ntfs-hard-drive-from-a-ubuntu-live-cd/

Comment: Do you have this problem still now? or fixed somehow. If fixed let us know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good chance the external drive is infected with malware that spreads using the AutoRun / AutoPlay functionality in Windows. Unfortunately there is usually a financial motive behind such malware - it can encrypt files on your system and then show you a message demanding payment for the restoration of your data - almost like a digital version of kidnapping. If your data is encrypted and you don't have a backup, the news is not good. If the malware is less sophisticated and all it has done is rename and change rights, there is still a chance of recovery, but you are going to need to find a VERY technically skilled (and patient) friend or company to assist you in recovering your data. You aren't going to learn these skills overnight if you don't already possess them.

The best option would be to entirely erase and reformat both your computer and your external drive, and restore from a clean backup. If you don't have a clean backup, you have probably lost your data permanently, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: It's easy to get the files back, you can skip permissions in Linux!

Comment: @HackToHell - it may be easy for you - I don't think it will necessarily be easy for the OP based on their questions. I think it's best they find someone who knows how to do this for them.

Comment: Holy paranoid much?  Something has been hidden and renamed unexpectedly... IT MUST BE A VIRUS TARGETING ME FOR EXTORTION!!!! ;)

Comment: @Bork Blatt nice infos thanks , i just recovered half of my files with a free recovery software , i am trying the linux option also , i can't format the whole thing it's 2 TB of data , and this happen to JPG files , i should never attached it to a computer which i don't know how up to date is it's anti virus/maleware application :(

Comment: @techie007 because we all know files rename themselves and change permissions on their own... right?

Comment: @steve Not on their own no, but it can (and does) happen when there's disk/filesystem corruption.  The fact they're all renamed to the SAME thing (and that it's an external drive) in this instance makes me lean more to that than a virus. But hey, we may never know... ;)

Comment: @techie007 I can agree with that :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a result of malware.

To restore the files and folders on the external hard drive so that they are visible and accessible, open an elevated command prompt (type `cmd` into the search field on the Start Menu, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and confirm the request).

Then type:

`attrib -h -r -s /s /d X:\*.*`

Note: Change X to be the drive letter of the external hard drive

The malware would have to be addressed with a program like MalwareBytes or Avast and check all drives on your system.

I see that you may be trying a recovery via Linux, but I figured a Windows option wouldn't hurt in the event someone else has something similar.